# Looping until the values in the list are exhausted

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list with sub-lists `k = [ ]`. 
I wrote a fragment in which I take sub-lists `k[0]` and `k[1]`, I compare, and I get a new list of `out = [ ]`:

```
  for i in range(len(k[0])):
      for j in range(len(k[1])):
          r = list(chain(k[0][i],k[1][j]))
          j = [i for i, _ in groupby(r)]
          if len(j) < len(r):
             out.append(j)
```

After doing the above code I would like replace list `k` in this way:

```
k = [out, k[2:]]
```

Then the `for` loop is about to be executed again, but with the new values `k[0]` and `k[1]` so until the sub-lists run out in `k[2:]`

I tried something with 'while' and 'try', but for now with a bad result.

And this is a larger piece of code to test:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, combinations, groupby

df = pd.read_csv("graph.csv", sep=';', encoding='utf-8')

g = nx.Graph()
g = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'nodes_1', 'nodes_2')

plt.show()


a1 = pd.Series([0] + df['nodes_2'][df['nodes_2']%2==0].values.tolist())
a2 = pd.Series(df['nodes_2'][df['nodes_2']%2==1].values.tolist())

b1, b2 = a1.apply(g.neighbors), a2.apply(g.neighbors)

c1, d1 = a1.values.tolist(), b1.values.tolist()
c2, d2 = a2.values.tolist(), b2.values.tolist()

e00=[]
for i in range(len(c1)):
    for j in range(len(d1[i])):
        if d1[i][j]%2==0:
           d = [c1[i],d1[i][j]]
           e00.append(d)

e01=[]
for i in range(len(c1)):
    for j in range(len(d1[i])):
        if d1[i][j]%2==1:
           d = [c1[i],d1[i][j]]
           e01.append(d)

e10=[]
for i in range(len(c2)):
    for j in range(len(d2[i])):
        if d2[i][j]%2==0:
           d = [c2[i],d2[i][j]]
           e10.append(d)

e11=[]
for i in range(len(c2)):
    for j in range(len(d2[i])):
        if d2[i][j]%2==1:
           d = [c2[i],d2[i][j]]
           e11.append(d)

a00 = pd.DataFrame(e00)
a01 = pd.DataFrame(e01)
a10 = pd.DataFrame(e10)
a11 = pd.DataFrame(e11)

a = input('Write a binary number. \n')

b=[]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    c = a[i:i+2]
    b.append(c)

print (b, '\n')

dct = {'00' : e00, '01' : e01, '10' : e10, '11' : e11}  

k=[]
for i in b:
    y = dct[i]
    k.append(y)

out=[]    
for i in range(len(k[0])):
    for j in range(len(k[1])):
        r = list(chain(k[0][i],k[1][j]))
        j = [i for i, _ in groupby(r)]
        if len(j) < len(r):
             out.append(j) 

print (k, '\n')
print (out, '\n')
```

And graph.csv:

```
    nodes_1 nodes_2
0   0       1
1   0       2
2   1       3
3   1       4
4   2       5
5   2       6
6   3       7
7   3       8
8   4       9
9   4       10
10  5       11
11  5       12
12  6       13
13  6       14
```

What do I want to do?

after typing the sample binary string: `001101`, I get the values assigned to the dictionary: `['00', '01', '11', '10', '01']`. In each letter `a00, a01, a10, a11` are the same data. My loop takes data matching '00' and compares it with data under '01'. A list `out` is created. As you can see the values `"11", "10", "01"` are still not used. Therefore, the `out` list will retrieve the next value for comparison and do the same as before. until exhaustion `['00', '01', '11', '10', '01']`. 
And I was thinking of replacing k = [out, k [2:]] so that the same loop was still being used.

Comment: A rule of thumb is usually that it is dangerous (and un-Pythonic) to alter a list while iterating over it. One of the idea's behind Python is that developer time is worth more than processing time, so instead of getting the most out of a CPU it is better to construct a new list. It requires some extra cycles (and memory), but it is more robust.

Comment: 1. please post an example containing input with corresponding output. 2. why is `pandas` tagged?
3. when using imports you have renamed (or not) include the import statements

Comment: When you tag `pandas` add sample data.

Comment: @Bharath I updated.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski what do you expect the output to be, because analzying for loops is pain for anyone without comments describing what it does .

Comment: @Bharath again updated :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski do you want chunk of 2-2 from the list for each iteration ? like if list is [1,2,3,4,5,6] , you want [1,2] then for next iteration you want [3,4] etc ?

Comment: @Ayodhyankit Paul first  for([1,2]) = out, then for([out, 3], and so on.
Of course, I'm talking about `['00', '01', '11', '10', '01']` iterations.

Comment: @Ayodhyankit Paul yes, exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach if it works for you , This is not an exact solution, You can take help , hint from it. 
As you commented out that you want 2-2 chuck but after one chuck you want that chuck to replace those two item something like :

```
first for itertation ==>> ['00', '01'] = out_list  now origional list become  [[out_list], '11', '10', '01']
for second iteration ==>> [[out_list], '11'] = out_list  now origional list become  [[out_list],'10', '01']
for third iteration ==>> [[out_list],10]  = out_list now origional list become  [[out_list],'01]

for forth iteration ==>> [[out_list],'01'] = out_list now origional list become [[out_list]]
```

Here is approach :

```
actual_list=['00', '01', '11', '10', '01']

def group(updated_list,actual_list):
    print(updated_list)  #This is just for showing output
    exit_condition = []
    for item in updated_list:

        if not isinstance(item,list):
            exit_condition.append(item)
    if not exit_condition:
        return 0
    else:
        out = []
        for index in range(0, len(updated_list), 2):
            k = updated_list[index:index + 2]
            #do you stuff with k[0] and k[1] before inserting to out list
            out.insert(len(out), k)


            for item in actual_list:
                out.insert(len(updated_list), item)

            updated_list = out

            return group(updated_list,actual_list[1:])






print(group(actual_list,actual_list[2:]))
```

output:

```
['00', '01', '11', '10', '01']
[['00', '01'], '11', '10', '01']
[[['00', '01'], '11'], '10', '01']
[[[['00', '01'], '11'], '10'], '01']
[[[[['00', '01'], '11'], '10'], '01']]
```

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski always :)